# Rust cannot represent Postgres numeric type as BigDecimal type

Tags: rust, serde, actix-web, rust-sqlx

I am writing simple rust web application using `actix-web` and `sqlx`.
I have struct `Book` with `price` field which should be mapped to postgres `NUMERIC` type. First I got error from `sqlx` that it was expecting `bigdecimal` type and suggested to enable this feature from cargo configuration, so I did. Then I imported `BigDecimal` from sqlx types and tried to use this type in my struct.

```
use sqlx::types::BigDecimal;
```

But I get this error:

```
12 |     pub price: BigDecimal,
   |     ^^^ the trait `configuration::_::_serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `BigDecimal`
```

I tried to find solution to this problem, one possible solution was to use `bigdecimal` crate directly with `serde` enabled. So I tried to use `bigdecimal` type instead of `sqlx` one:

```
use bigdecimal::BigDecimal;
```

But now I got different error:

```
the trait `sqlx::Type<Postgres>` is not implemented for `bigdecimal::BigDecimal`
```

Here is code I am using:

Book struct:

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc,};
use chrono::serde::ts_seconds;
//use sqlx::types::BigDecimal;
use bigdecimal::BigDecimal;


#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
pub struct Book {
    pub author: String,
    pub title: String,
    pub pages: i32,
    pub price: BigDecimal,
    #[serde(with = "ts_seconds")]
    pub published_at: DateTime<Utc>
}
```

function that tries to insert `Book` data into database:

```
pub async fn insert_book(data: &Book, pool: &PgPool) -> Result<(), sqlx::Error> {
    sqlx::query!(
        r#"
            INSERT INTO books
            (id, author, title, pages, price, published_at)
            VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
        "#,
        Uuid::new_v4(),
        data.author,
        data.title,
        data.pages,
        data.price,
        data.published_at
    )
        .execute(pool)
        .await
        .map_err(|e| {
            e
        })?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Simple POST endpoint:

```
#[post("/book")]
pub async fn add_new_book(data: web::Form<Book>, pool: web::Data<PgPool>) -> impl Responder {
    match insert_book(&data, &pool).await {
        Ok(_) => HttpResponse::Ok(),
        Err(e) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError()
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
secrecy = { version = "0.8", features = ["serde"] }
actix-web = "4.3.1"
serde = { version = "1", features = ["derive"]}
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["macros", "rt-multi-thread"] }
uuid = { version = "1.3.4", features = ["v4"] }
config = "0.11"
chrono = { version = "0.4.26", features = ["serde"] }
bigdecimal = { version = "0.2.0", features = ["serde"] }


[dependencies.sqlx]
version = "0.6.3"
default-features = false
features = [
    "runtime-actix-rustls",
    "macros",
    "postgres",
    "uuid",
    "chrono",
    "migrate",
    "bigdecimal"
]
```

Not sure how to fix this problem, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of the bigdecimal crate did you add to your dependencies? You need to match the version that sqlx uses (for the latest sqlx, that would be bigdecimal 0.3.0).

Comment: I was using bigdecimal 0.2.0. Let me switch to 0.3.0 and try again.

Comment: Yea you are right, it works now. I guess I did not pay attention to versions. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to match the version of `bigdecimal` that sqlx uses (for sqlx 0.6.3, that would be bigdecimal 0.3.0).

It's actually a [dependency of `sqlx_core`](https://crates.io/crates/sqlx-core/0.6.3/dependencies)

Comment: Yea problem was that I was using wrong `bigdecimal` version

Comment: I know, just posted my comment as an answer. It is a Q& **A** site, after all.